# Component gives error before api is able to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

So I have a react app that fetches data from an express server and displays it in a component called 'Articles'. The problem I'm having is that I get an error in my Article component saying `data.map is not a function` which I assume is because `data` does not exist yet because the api has not finished fetching.

I tried to solve this by implementing a loader and updating the state when the fetch is complete. Just to note that when I use componentWillMount everything works fine.

*App.js*

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    loading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() { // componentWillMount works fine
    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      fetch('/api')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) =>
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            data: data,
          })
        )
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { data, loading, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className={styles.container}>
          {loading ? (
            <SkeletonLoader loading={loading} />
          ) : (
            <Articles loading={loading} data={data} />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Articles.jsx*

```
const Articles = ({ data, loading }) => {
    return (         
         <Center>
                 {data.map((articles, index) => {
                     return (<h1 key={index}>stuff displayed here</h1>) // data is properly displayed here
                 })}
         </Center>
    )
}
```

Here is express api if it helps:

```
app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    googleTrends.dailyTrends(
      {
        trendDate: new Date('2020-12-10'),
        geo: 'US',
      },
      function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500);
        } else {
          return res.send(response);
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: There might be a call to `render` before the state change from `componentDidMount`. Replacing the call to map with `(data || []).map(...)` should do the trick if that is the case.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same error

Comment: Are you confident that `data` is an array?